# Shell script log file overwrites itself

Tags: logging, sh

Every time I run this shell script the log file will overwrites itself and does not just add a new line in the logfile? how can I accomplice that ?

```
#/bin/sh

exec &> logfile.txt


DATE=`date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"`
mydbuser=""
dbuserpassword=""
mydatabase=""

mysqldump --user=$mydbuser --password=$dbuserpassword --default-character-set=utf8 $mydatabase| > /$mydatabase/$mydatabase-$DATE.sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use >> if you want to append to file.